# Android app not installed permenantly in AVD

Tags: android, android-studio

I work on an Android project . I compiled my application on Virtual device and it works fine but when i close the application it vanished from my device and i can't run it again. But it's shown into installed apps when i go to settings and see my apps.

I copy/paste the compiled `app-debug.apk` to my device and try to install it manually however it install successfully but i am not able to open it.

Comment: compile and start form android studio, next close it(keep android studio open - better in debug mode), check to see if you don't do some weird stuff and then try to start again and look in logcat.

Comment: 10-16 00:56:20.292  16417-16417/com.bluestacks.home **bold** D/S2P.Blue.Master﹕ App installed: null

Comment: May be there is a problem in my settings.I just create new projects copy/paste my files and now it works fine .Thanks